# Why does SSMS treat two t's as one character

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms

Say I write the following select statement:

```
select distincttype_of_reading
```

And I move the cursor to either of the t's and press the key to move to the next one, it will skip over one of the t's treating the tt combination as one character.

Same as if I press delete it will delete both of the t's rather than just one.
If I press backspace it will delete one at a time however.

This isnt a problem as such, im just curious as to why if at all there is an explaination?

Comment: Can you reproduce this with other identifier that contain two `t`s? Can't reproduce it in SSMS2012 and don't have SSMS2008 unfortunately.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, something like this: select ffffffgetttgg from ffffffgetttgg where ffffffgetttgg will always result in skipping over two f's at a time

Comment: That is what I meant. Humm strange.

Comment: seems to be present with certain characters

Comment: Have you customized your setup? Specific thing I'm thinking of, are you using a non-standard font?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Yes this is in Calibri font, I have just tried in the standard font and is not an issue. Clearly something to do with using non-standard font then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be font related. The Calibri font supports [ligatures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographic_ligature) and so, apparently does the 2008 editor (the 2012 editor doesn't have this issue).

So `tt` is being treated as a single glyph, for most purposes.